# request returns status code 200 locally, 503 on ec2 in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, http, amazon-ec2

So I have a web scraping script that when run locally, works just fine.  However, when I take the same script and run it on ec2, it returns a status code of 503.

Here's the code:

```
for i in range(1, 26):
    base_url = f"https://www.congress.gov/members?pageSize=100&page={i}"
    req      = requests.get(base_url)
    if req.status_code == 200:
        scraper  = BeautifulSoup(req.text, features = 'lxml')
```

Works like a charm on my local computer, but the status code is always 503 when I run it on an ubuntu instance on ec2.

I started on a t2 micro, but upgraded it to a t2.medium because I read the 503 error might mean that my system is overloaded (though I don't see why that'd be the case for for my script)

I also tried changing the `https` part of the address to `http`, but that didn't work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: At a guess, the 503 response is because your request comes from an IP block that the target website has decided to block scraping attempts (or possibly all requests) from.

Comment: Right.  Now, if you were running a web SERVER, and requests to that server were getting a 503, then that might indicate a performance issue.  But if you are making a request of another server and you get a 503, that's either down for maintenance, or you are being blocked.